# How to say "Nice to see you again"?

Tags: traducción, saludos

If a doctor was seeing a patient again and wanted to say:

> Nice to see you again!

How would he say so in Spanish?

Comment: Es agradable verlo (de nuevo)/(otra vez)

Comment: Welcome!!! in the StackExchange network is good to do a prior research before asking, because your question will be close, http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: How confusing. I've been taught in Mexico " que gusto te verte". Sometimes it's so difficult to know what is correct in the area which you are speaking

Answer (score 13):

In a somewhat formal context like that, the right expression would be *Me alegro de volver a verle*.

Comment: In neutral context would be _Me alegro de volver a verte_ or _Me alegro de verte de nuevo_.

Comment: @lorddarkangel O _Me alegro de verte nuevamente_. Pero nunca _Me alegro de vuelverte a ver_ :)

Comment: It is more usual to say "Me alegro de verte" that "Me alegro de volver a verte". The part of "volver a" ("again") is unnecesary, as any time you see someone you are seeing him again. I think without that it sounds better, if a literal transalation is not mandatory.

Comment: @Flamma: We could say the same in English: *Nice to see you* instead of *Nice to see you again*. But you don't use both constructs in exactly the same situations. Maybe in an informal context you would be more likely to shorten the sentence.

Comment: @Gorpik I don't think those distinctions apply in Spanish. I don't think "Me alegro de verle" is more informal than "Me alegro de volver a verle", just much more usual, in my opinion. Maybe in the case of the doctor, another courtesy sentences would be more usual like "¿Cómo está usted?".

Answer (score 12):

There are different ways to express the same salutation in spanish:

> ¡Qué bueno verte (de nuevo)!
>
> ¡Qué gusto verte (de nuevo)!
>
> ¡Me alegro de verte (de nuevo)!
>
> ¡Me alegro de (volver a) verte!

Comment: You could also get away with taking `Qué` out completely, but it wouldn't have as much emphasis on HOW good it is to see the person again.

Answer (score 4):

You can say:

> Encantado de volver a verte/verle.

Answer (score 2):

Given the context of your targeted sentence, "Nice to see you again".. I, as a native speaker of English, understand this to be subtle.  For instance,

"You look nice"
----- vs -----
"You look great"

[The definition of nice](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20nice) will explain that part.

So, my immediate idea for a translation of "nice to see you again" would be.

> *[Es]* Bueno verte de nuevo

It's not great, it's not stupdenous, it's just good, it's nice, like the feeling of sleeping on a clean bed with clean sheets.

> ¡Qué bueno verte (de nuevo)!

which was given by alonso.torres is about the best translation I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Colombia,  actually there is a trend or a zeitgeist to say:

> ¡Me encantó verte!

Comment: This is a goodbye not a greeting.

Answer (score 1):

In Mexico, it is also used:

> Me da gusto verte

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, people often use "Qué bueno" in this situation.

If it is an older adult, or someone you want to be formal with:

> Qué bueno verle de nuevo.

Or

> Qué bueno verle otra vez.

If it is a friend, or a less formal situation then:

> Qué bueno verte de nuevo

or

> Qué bueno verte otra vez.

Comment: Qué bueno que aportaras esta respuesta tan interesante :) ¡Bienvenido a [spanish.se]!

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

> ¡Me alegro de verte de nuevo!